# multiple plots with function matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I created a function that creates a plot, basically the function looks like this:

```
def draw_line(array):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(array)
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to call this function when wanting to do multiple plots in a figure. In particular, I wanted to do something like:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
for i in list:
axes[i] = draw_line(*list[i])
```

However, what I get is an empty grid with the actual plots below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to call a new plt.subplots() each time you call draw_line(). Instead, you want to use an existing axis object. In this case you want to pass in the axis for each subplot with its corresponding data. Then plot the two together.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw_line(ax,array):
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(array)

# example data and figure
example_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,2,5],[3,2,5],[3,2,5],[3,2,5]]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

# loop over elements in subplot and data, plot each one
for ax,i in zip(axes.flatten(),example_list):
    draw_line(ax,i)
```

Output looks like this
[image]

Comment: Note, the pictures on the bottom row are all the same cause their data is the same. Just got lazy there. Also, the function draw_line() can be as crazy as you like, just pass in the individual axis object you want the data to be plotted on as in this example.

Comment: Thank you very much, just tried it and it works well!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @user2241910,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
example_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,2,5],[5,2,3],[1,3,1],[5,3,5]]

for i,data in enumerate(example_list):
    ax = plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    ax.plot(data)
```

Produces:

[image]